# How to prevent highlighting of table row in next segment?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

When I select a table row and click `'Ok'` under `city` tab, it is highlighting the row but when I change the tab to `town`, it is highlighting the same row in the `town` tab even though I did not select it.That is if I highlight second and third row under `city` tab, it is highlighting second and third row under `town` tab as well without me doing anything. Following is my code

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CityCell
    switch (segCtrl.selectedSegmentIndex)
    {
    case 0:
        myCell.myLabel.text = cityName[indexPath.row]
        break
    case 1:
        myCell.myLabel.text  = townName[indexPath.row]
        break
    default:break
    }
    return myCell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){

let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)

let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha:0.5)
    })
let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: { (action) -> Void in
})
   alertController.addAction(ok)
   alertController.addAction(cancel)
present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

How do I prevent this highlighting from happening in next tab and confine it to where I actually selected the row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm working with objective-c. So, sorry if my swift code is wrong.

```
// global variable which carry selection-indexPath
var citySelectedIndexPaths = [IndexPath]()
var townSelectedIndexPaths = [IndexPath]()

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CityCell

    // add this line
    myCell.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha:1.0) // default color

    switch (segCtrl.selectedSegmentIndex)
    {
    case 0:
        myCell.myLabel.text = cityName[indexPath.row]
        if citySelectedIndexPaths.contains(indexPath) {
          myCell.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha:0.5)
        }
        break
    case 1:
        myCell.myLabel.text  = townName[indexPath.row]
        if townSelectedIndexPaths.contains(indexPath) {
          myCell.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha:0.5)
        }
        break
    default:break
    }
    return myCell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){

let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)

let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha:0.5)

    // save selection indexPath
    switch (segCtrl.selectedSegmentIndex)
    {
    case 0:
        if citySelectedIndexPaths.contains(indexPath) {
          let indexValue = citySelectedIndexPaths.indexOf(indexPath)
          citySelectedIndexPaths.removeAtIndex(indexValue)
        } else {
          citySelectedIndexPaths.append(indexPath);
        }
        break
    case 1:
        if townSelectedIndexPaths.contains(indexPath) {
          let indexValue = townSelectedIndexPaths.indexOf(indexPath)
          townSelectedIndexPaths.removeAtIndex(indexValue)
        } else {
          townSelectedIndexPaths.append(indexPath);
        }
        break
    default:break
    }

    })
let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: { (action) -> Void in
})
   alertController.addAction(ok)
   alertController.addAction(cancel)
present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: This doesn't keep the selection when I come back.

Comment: Yes, It just reset the cell to normal when you change the tab. If you want keep the selection, you should save the selection indexPath.row in array or global variable when you tap 'OK'. then use if statement to decide the cell should highlighted in switch statement.

Comment: This is working but it is remembering only the last row selected. That is if I select three rows, it is highlighting only the last selected row and remaining two rows are unselected.

Comment: I don't know, if we can select multiple row. You question isn't complete. So we need change the the variable to array

Answer (score 0):

Now in your code, you set background manually.

```
cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha:0.5)
```

But you did not reset `cell.backgroundColor` after you select other cell. So you need to store current selected `cell's indexPath` and call `reloadData` each time you select new cell in `ok UIAlertAction`. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, just perform cell with selected or unselected stage.